# Jquery scroll event causing performance issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, scroll

I'm trying to use the browser scroll event to place a block of html based on the amount a user has scrolled. The code works but it is causing a huge performance issue which basically forces my browser to freeze.

Any insight as to why and what I could do to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#content').scroll(function () {
    var scroll = $('#content').scrollTop();
    var $controls = $(".controls").clone();
    if (scroll > 200) {
        $(".controls").remove();
        $('#header').append($controls);
    }
    else {
        $(".controls").remove();
        $('.banner').append($controls);
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: your could try caching your variables to start.  These variables will be called hundreds of times over and over

Comment: important to understand that scroll event fires many times a second

Comment: Yeah, scroll fires like crazy. You could look into using some sort of debounce or throttling.

Comment: +1 for debouncing/throttling  http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Answer (score 14):

First, discovering elements in the DOM is an expensive activity, so cache your jQuery objects.

Second, `.append()` moves elements around so `.clone()` and `remove()` should be unnecessary.

This gives :

```
var $$ = {//cache of jQuery objects
    content: $('#content'),
    controls: $(".controls"),
    header: $("#header"),
    banner: $('.banner')
};
$('#content').scroll(function() {
    $controls.appendTo(($$.content.scrollTop() > 200) ? $$.header : $$.banner);
});
```

Now, you can work on reducing the frequency at which the handler is called, which can be achieved as follows :

```
var $$ = {//cache of jQuery objects
    content: $('#content'),
    controls: $(".controls"),
    header: $("#header"),
    banner: $('.banner')
};

var scrollHandling = {
    allow: true,
    reallow: function() {
        scrollHandling.allow = true;
    },
    delay: 50 //(milliseconds) adjust to the highest acceptable value
};

$('#content').scroll(function() {
    if(scrollHandling.allow) {
        $controls.appendTo(($$.content.scrollTop() > 200) ? $$.header : $$.banner);
        scrollHandling.allow = false;
        setTimeout(scrollHandling.reallow, scrollHandling.delay);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `scroll` function is called for every movement of the scrollbar. That can potentially be a lot of times, so you need to be careful how much code you are running and certainly how much manipulation of the DOM you are doing.

In this case, you'll be repeating a lot of the same actions (`clone`, `append`, `remove`) as the scrolling is occurring, but it appears that you only want to flip between two states as you cross back and forth over that 200 `scroll` value. You could potentially solve most of the performance issues with something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var thresholdCrossed = false;

$('#content').scroll(function () {
    var scroll = $('#content').scrollTop();
    var threshold = 200;
    if (scroll > threshold && !thresholdCrossed) {
        var controls = $(".controls").clone();
        $(".controls").remove();
        $('#header').append(controls);
    } else if (scroll <= threshold && thresholdCrossed) {
        var controls = $(".controls").clone();
        $(".controls").remove();
        $('.banner').append(controls);
    }
    thresholdCrossed = scroll > threshold;
});

</script>
```

You can do additional work that some of the other answers describe to help reduce wasted resources, but this should give you a general idea of how to hopefully help the main performance concern of constantly modifying the DOM as you scroll. I would probably suggest some combination of this along with the answer provided by @Kolink so that you are truly limiting the DOM manipulation to the least amount necessary.

Comment: Thanks Marc, this is very helpful. I am unfamiliar with some of the syntax so I will look forward to deciphering everything to expand my general knowledge with JS. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure thing. I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LC3mm/) you can play with to show this off a bit. The `thresholdCrossed` works like a flag and will only cause the code in the `if` statements to fire when you are changing states. Good luck!

Comment: Awesome. This might be easier for me to work with because I plan to add in a fade effect so it doesn't feel 'jumpy'

Comment: imho this is the correct answer. Throttling/debouncing and caching as Beetroot-Beetroot suggest is definitely valuable but first and foremost the program logic should be sound and this eliminates the usage of throttling. With suggested code-snippet the script is only excecuted at the moment of crossing the threshold.

Answer (score 2):

You are cloning all `.controls` elements every tick of scrolling, even when it is not needed.

I would suggest cloning the controls on `ready` and setting it to `display:none`. Then, just toggle the display based on the scroll position.

---

On re-reading your question, it looks like you're just moving the controls element from the `header` to the `banner`? In that case, you don't even need a clone. However I strongly suggest adding `id="controls"` to the controls element, and `id="banner"` - use IDs instead of classes in general if there is only one.

```
document.getElementById('content').onscroll = function() {
    document.getElementById(this.scrollTop > 200 ? "banner" : "header")
       .appendChild(document.getElementById('controls'));
};
```

Comment: I see what you are saying Kolink. Makes perfect since. However, I can't just simply toggle the display based on the scroll position because I actually need the scroll position to dictate where the .controls appears. That is why I had to setup the clone so I could append it and remove it based on scroll position. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: The solution I am suggesting uses a clone too. Just one, that is created at the start of the page being loaded. Toggling the display of an element is much faster than cloning, and you can make it even better. Hold on, I'll edit my answer with some code.

Comment: This is great Kolink, thanks! I'm going to look through Marc Baumbach response too and compare both. I am unfamiliar with some of the techniques he and you both used so at the very least this is a great learning experience. The only issue I might run into with the above example is the ability to add additional effects. I was trying to get the groundwork setup first and then I planned on adding a nice fadeIn, fadeOut to the functionality. Thanks again!

Comment: I was wondering, why did you use getElementById vs $('#content')?

Answer (score 0):

Every time the scroll bar moves jQuery has to go into the DOM to get the variables you references.  To start cache the variables so jQuery doesnt have to do twice the work.

```
          var content = $('#content');

          content.scroll(function(){


          });
```