# Moving Element according to vertical Scroll - most performant way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, scroll

I'm building a little script to manipulate elements according to vertical page-scrolling.
This solution basically works fine, but I'm wondering if there is a more performant way to do this. I would love to keep everything smooth and fluent.

http://jsfiddle.net/d4NCE/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var element = $("#element1");
var elementOffset = element.offset().top;
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var distanceEntry = windowHeight*0.8; // distance from element
var distanceExit = windowHeight*0.2; // distance from element
var entry = elementOffset-distanceEntry; // entry point in px from pagetop
var exit = elementOffset-distanceExit; // exit point in px from pagetop
var stepping = (exit-entry)/100; // px to percentage
$("#entry").css("top", entry); // placing entry-marker
$("#exit").css("top", exit); // placing exit-marker

$(window).scroll(function(){

    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 
    var value = (scroll-entry)/stepping; // CALCULATION PROGRESS OF ANIMATION

    if(value>=100) {value=100;} // cutting top and bottom
    if(value<=0) {value=0;} // cutting top and bottom
    value = Math.round(value); // to integer


    $("#element1").css("left", value); // WRITING VALUE TO ELEMENT

    $("#head").html("Element-Movement in Percent: " + value);
    });

});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since the `scroll` event fires so often, you might see some slight improvements in performance if you move as much logic out of the scroll event as possible.

In your example all of the element selection could be moved out of the listener, and the if statements don't need `>=` and `<=`.  `<` and `>` will achieve the same thing.
e.g.

```
var $win = $(window);
var $element1 = $("#element1");
var $head = $("#head");
$win.scroll(function(){

    var scroll = $win.scrollTop(); 
    var value = (scroll-entry)/stepping; // CALCULATION PROGRESS OF ANIMATION

    if(value>100) {value=100;} // cutting top and bottom
    if(value<0) {value=0;} // cutting top and bottom
    value = Math.round(value); // to integer


    $element1.css("left", value); // WRITING VALUE TO ELEMENT

    $head.html("Element-Movement in Percent: " + value);
});
```

Not sure it this will give you noticable perf gains, but it shouldn't hurt.

Comment: Thanks. I just found this approach, looks very promising: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14658295/1629907

What do you guys think, this should improve performance drastically, right? I have trouble to actually testing the performance somehow else then... looking at it or checking the code.

Comment: Nice!  The only thing i'd say about that approach is that rate limiting with setTimeout is a mistake.  60 fps is 16.6ms between actions, and setTimeout is only accurate up to ~40ms.  Especially if you are using it repeatedly.  you could use setTimeout(..., 0) but that doesn't really help since the scroll event is asynchronous anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, by now I finalized my little script.
Again I would love to have some Input if there are ways to improve performance, or if there is a better approach to achieve my goal.
Already tried to store all important information in variables, so there are as few dom-scans as possible. Thank you guys!

Have a look at the script: http://jsfiddle.net/sVeXT/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

(function parallax() { 

    var win = $(window);
    var windowHeight = win.height();
    var distanceEntry = windowHeight*0.85; // distance from element
    var distanceExit = windowHeight*0.20; // distance from element

    var elements = []; 

    function elementsSetup() { // scans DOM for Elements and forwards their specs to "Element"-Constructor
        elements = [];
        $(".element").each(function(i, el){ // iteration through elements
            var height = $(el).height();
            var offset = $(el).offset().top;
            elements.push(new Element(i, el, height, offset));  // link to constructor and adding to array
            });
        };      
    elementsSetup();

    function Element(i, el, height, offset) { // constructor
        this.el = el;
        this.height = height;
        this.i = i;
        this.offset = offset;
        this.entry = offset-distanceEntry+height/2; // calculations to center element 
        this.exit = offset-windowHeight/2+height/2; // calculations to center element 
        this.stepping = (this.exit-this.entry)/100; // to percentage 
        }

    $(window).scroll( function(){ // when scrolling writing to CSS of elements
        var scroll = win.scrollTop();
        var x = elements.length-1;
        for (var i = x; i>=0; i--) {
            var value = valueCap( (scroll-elements[i].entry)/elements[i].stepping );
            $(elements[i].el).css("left", value);
            }  
        });

    $(window).resize(function() { // in case of window-resize values are redefined
        windowHeight = win.height();
        elementsSetup();
        });

    function valueCap(val) { // caps value 0-100
        if(val>100) {val=100;}
        if(val<0) {val=0;}
        return val;
        }

    })();

});
```